# Взаимодействие с сервером: форма в форме

Tags: javascript, форма, ссылки, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте! 
У меня возникла проблема, связанная с взаимодействием с сервером.
Задача такая. У меня есть форма, в которую с серверной части подгружается список пользователей,естественно, каждый раз разный, голубые квадратики рядом - ссылки на их страницы. 
Если ссылки не в форме, то тут решение я знаю, вернее мой серверный программист знает - он делает ссылки рабочими через элемент формы.
В моем случае получается форма в форме, что недопустимо. Вопрос, как реализовать мою задачу? Это JS?
Спасибо за ответ!
Схематично прикладываю то, что должно быть.PS Мой коллега работает на Python.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Ссылка внутри формы - допустимое решение, она ведь не загружает другую страницу внутрь этой формы. Или у Вас загружает?

Comment: Вы никак не описали саму "задачу", что конкретно вам нужно сделать? Что значит "рабочие ссылки"?

Comment: Пусть Ваш программист найдёт способ сделать ссылки рабочими без элемента формы. Раз нельзя в html вложенные формы, что тут ещё поделаешь?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать для ссылок *ссылки,* а не формы с кнопками.
Ну ведь логично же??